# Load Log With 15 Columns Separated By Spaces But Last Column Contains Spaces

Tags: r, shell, logging, csv, read.table

I have a log file that has 15 columns separated by spaces, but the last column in the log file is an email subject line and contains spaces. I'm not sure how to read a file like this into R.
The last column looks like: SUBJ:X XXX XXX XXX  XXX XXX
I know how to read in a space delimited file using read.table, but i'm not sure what to do, given the last column.

Comment: Is the log file, by any chance, fixed width?

Comment: no, it contains email information. The widths vary.

Answer (score 1):

If the last column always starts with "SUBJ", you might be able to use something like this.

For this example, we'll make up a sample file named "myFile":

```
cat("aaaa bbb ccccc SUBJ:X Y ZZZ\naaaaaa bbbbbbb ccccccc SUBJ:X XXX\naaa b ccccc\n", file = "myFile.txt")
```

Use `readLines` to read in `myFile.txt` (or your actual log file). Note that the third line doesn't have a subject.

```
myFile <- readLines("myFile.txt")
myFile
# [1] "aaaa bbb ccccc SUBJ:X Y ZZZ"      
# [2] "aaaaaa bbbbbbb ccccccc SUBJ:X XXX"
# [3] "aaa b ccccc"
```

Use some regular expressions to match the last "column":

```
myMatches <- gregexpr("SUBJ:.*$", myFile)
```

Use that information to read in your `data.frame`:

```
cbind(read.table(text = unlist(regmatches(myFile, myMatches, invert=TRUE))), 
      subj = sapply(regmatches(myFile, myMatches), 
                    function(x) ifelse(length(x) > 0, x, NA)))
#       V1      V2      V3         subj
# 1   aaaa     bbb   ccccc SUBJ:X Y ZZZ
# 2 aaaaaa bbbbbbb ccccccc   SUBJ:X XXX
# 3    aaa       b   ccccc         <NA>
```

Comment: This is seems like a good solution, but there are some emails without subjects lines and that is returning an error.

Comment: @user1507889, when there is no subject, does the term "SUBJ" still show in the line?

Comment: Yeah, no SUBJ. Just blank space.

Comment: @user1507889, try my update and see if it works for those cases.

Comment: Ah. That fixes that problem. Thank you for your help. I'm running into  "Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 7 did not have 16 elements" when trying to load in the table. It seems that some of lines without a subject line have less columns than other lines. The line 7 has 15 elements.

Answer (score 0):

Read it in with readLines, then use gsub to substitute commas for the first 14 spaces.

This shows how to do it with a simple example:

```
  gsub("^(\\w\\s)(\\w\\s)(\\w\\s)(\\w\\s)", "\\1,\\2,\\3,\\4," , 
                                 paste(letters[1:8], collapse=" ") )
  [1] "a ,b ,c ,d ,e f g h"
```